# "The two youths walked back, recounting/each recounting to the/each other"

Tags: word-usage

> A. The two youths walked back, **each recounting** to **the other** what had happened to them.
>   B. The two youths walked back, **recounting** to **each other** what had happened to them.

Which sentence is more common?

Comment: It's hard to choose between them: they are both clear and correct. On balance I would prefer the first, but Ngram cannot find any instances of the first- only the second.

Comment: C. The two youths walked back, recounting what had happened to them.

"Recounting" is a valid word but it's not commonly (or colloquially used).  Typically a less formal structure would be something like:

D. The two youths walked back, talking about what had happened.